# How to append only the numbers in a row to a variable using float and an if statement in a for loop

Tags: python, for-loop, if-statement

Given a data set with the goal of graphing the data these issues arise:

- The header is an entry in the list,
- Some of the entries are blank (data missing),
- Even the numbers are in the form of strings

```
income=[]
fertility=[]
for row in csv:
  income.append(row[2])
  fertility.append(row[3])

print(income)
print(fertility)
```

I am trying to modify the above for loop that appends only the numerical values of the row using the float function coded below.

```
def isNumeric(s):
   try:
      s = float(s)
      return True
   except:
      return False
```

Below is my attempt, that is not appending the numerical values of the rows only giving me blank sets for income and fertility.

```
income=[]
fertility=[]
for row in csv:
  if isNumeric(row[2])=='True' and isNumeric(row[3])=='True':
    float(row[2])
    float(row[3])
    income.append(float(row[2]))
    fertility.append(float(row[3]))



print(income)
print(fertility)
```

Comment: `True == 'True'` is not true. Just get rid of the `=='True'`, you don't need to compare booleans explicitly.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this more simply by just doing both `float` conversions in a single `try/except`:

```
income = []
fertility = []
for row in csv:
    try:
        i, f = float(row[2]), float(row[3])
        income.append(i)
        fertility.append(f)
    except ValueError:
        pass
```

If either `float()` call raises `ValueError`, nothing will be appended, and the loop will just continue on to the next row.

Answer (score 0):

Samwise's response is a good one - it's simple and it is very pythonic - it tries to change the strings into floats and if that fails, it doesn't update the lists.

If you want your code to work, though, you can try it with these corrections:

```
income=[]
fertility=[]
for row in csv:
  if isNumeric(row[2]) and isNumeric(row[3]):
    income.append(float(row[2]))
    fertility.append(float(row[3]))

print(income)
print(fertility)
```